# Let $ f_n: (a, b) \to \mathbb R $ be a sequence of functions that satisfies the following hypotheses:

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, differential, sequence-of-function

> $ f_n $ is twice differentiable in (a, b);

> There is $ c \in (a, b) $ such that $ (f_n’(c)) $ is a bounded sequence;

> $(f_n'')$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of functions in (a, b).

> Prove that if $f_n$ simply converges to a function $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb R$, then $f$ is a class $C^1$.

The class $C^1$ consists of all differentiable functions whose derivative is continuous, and in $C^1$ the zeroth and first derivatives are continuous.

From the hypothesis Isn't it straightforward that $x_n$ is $C^1$?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Yes, it is clear each $f_n$ is in $C^1$, but it is not obvious that the limit function is in $C^1$.

Comment: Do you know about equicontinuity and the Arzela-Ascoli theorem?

Comment: When you put your question up on MSE with a bounty for a best answer, you should either award the bounty, or explain why you decided not to award the bounty. Just walking away with no further comment is not good practice IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Thm: (Arzela-Ascoli). Suppose $(g_n)$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ such that $(g_n)$ is uniformly equicontinuous and pointwise bounded on $[a,b].$ Then there is a subsequence of $(g_n)$ that converges uniformly on $[a,b].$

This version of A-A will be used for the given problem. A more general version is Thm. 11.6.9 at https://www.jirka.org/ra/html/sec_arzelaascoli.html

For our problem, we assume $f_1,f_2,\dots \in C^2[a,b],$ $f_n'(c)$ is bounded for some $c\in [a,b],$ and $f_n''$ is uniformy bounded on $[a,b].$ Assume further that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $[a,b].$ We want to prove that $f\in C^1[a,b].$

Proof: There exists $C$ such that $|f_n''|\le C$ on $[a,b].$ It follows that for $x,y\in [a,b],$ the MVT implies

$$|f'(x)-f_n'(y)|\le C|y-x|.$$

This implies $(f_n')$ is uniformly equitcontinuous on $[a,b].$ Furthermmore, since there is $C_1$ such that $|f_n'(c)|\le C_1$ for all $n,$ we have

$$|f_n'(x)|\le |f_n'(x)-f_n'(c)| + |f_n'(c)| $$ $$\le C|x-c| + C_1 \le C(b-a) + C_1.$$

Thus $f_n'$ is uniformly bounded on $[a,b].$

Apply A-A to see there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}'$ converging uniformly to some $h$ on $[a,b].$ Because each $f_{n_k}'$ is continuous, so is $h.$ Fixing $x_0\in [a,b],$ we have for any $x$ that

$$f_{n_k}(x)= f_{n_k}(x_0) + \int_x^{x_0}f_{n_k}'.$$

Letting $k\to\infty,$ we get

$$f(x)= f(x_0) + \int_x^{x_0}h.$$

Since $h$ is continuous, $f\in C^1[a,b].$

We're not quite done, because your problem occurs on some $(a,b),$ not $[a,b].$ But our work above shows $f\in C^1[a',b']$ for all $a<a'<b'<b,$ and that implies $f\in C^1(a,b).$

Comment: My previous answer was "Hint: $f_n''$ uniformly bounded on $(a,b)$ implies $\{f_n'\}$ is uniformly Lipschitz there (by the MVT). Hence $\{f_n'\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous on $(a,b)$. And we're given there is $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f_n'(c)$ is bounded. Hmm ... Arzela-Ascoli ... hmm "  I decided to go to a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $M>0$ such that $|f''_{n}(x)|\leq M$ and $|f'_{n}(c)|\leq M$
for all $x\in(a,b)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

Claim 1: The sequence $(f'_{n})$ is uniformly bounded on $(a,b)$.

Proof of Claim 1: Let $x\in(a,b)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. By mean-value
theorem, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|f'_{n}(x)-f'_{n}(c)\right| & = & \left|f''(\xi_{n,x})(x-c)\right|\\
 & \leq & M(b-a).
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $|f'_{n}(x)|\leq|f'_{n}(c)|+M(b-a)\leq M(b-a+1).$

---

Claim 2: There exists a subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ of $(f_{n})$ such
that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{n_{k}}'(x)$ exists for each $x\in(a,b)$.

Proof of Claim 2: Since for each $x\in(a,b)$, $\{f_{n}'(x)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded, there exists a strictly increasing function $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$
such that $(f'_{\phi(n)}(x))_{n}$ is convergent for each $x\in(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$.
This is known as Cantor Diagonal Argument. For the sake of completeness
and to facilitate those who do not know such argument, I include a
complete proof.

Fix an enumeration $\{r_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
for $\mathbb{Q}\cap(a,b)$. Since $(f_{n}'(r_{1}))_{n}$ is a bounded
sequence, it has a convergent subsequence $(f_{\theta_{1}(n)}'(r_{1}))_{n}$,
where $\theta_{1}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a strictly
increasing function.
For the bounded sequence $(f_{\theta_{1}(n)}'(r_{2}))_{n}$, we can
choose a convergent subsequence $(f_{\theta_{1}\circ\theta_{2}(n)}'(r_{2}))_{n}$,
where $\theta_{2}:\mathbb{\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}}$ is a
strictly increasing function. Note that $(f_{\theta_{1}\circ\theta_{2}(n)}'(x))_{n}$
converges for $x\in\{r_{1},r_{2}\}$. Repeating this argument recursively,
we obtain strictly increasing functions $\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots,\theta_{m}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$
such that $(f_{\theta_{1}\circ\theta_{2}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{m}(n)}'(x))_{n}$
is convergent for $x\in\{r_{1},r_{2},\ldots,r_{m}\}$. Define $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$
by $\phi(n)=\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{n}(n)$, then $\phi$
is strictly increasing. Moreover, $(f_{\phi(n)}'(x))_{n}$ is convergent
for $x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(a,b)$.

We include the details of proof.
We verify that $\phi$ is strictly increasing: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(n+1) & = & (\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{n})\circ\theta_{n+1}(n+1)\\
 & \geq & (\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{n})(n+1)\\
 & > & (\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{n})(n)\\
 & = & \phi(n).
\end{eqnarray*}
In the above, we have used the fact that $\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{n}$
is strictly increasing and $\xi(n)\geq n$ whenever $\xi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing function.

We verify that $(f'_{\phi(n)}(x))_{n}$ is convergent for all $x\in(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$.
Let $x\in(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, then $x=r_{k}$ for a unique $k$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Since $(f_{\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{k}(n)}'(r_{k}))_{n}$
is convergent, there exists $N$ such that $|f_{\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{k}(n)}'(r_{k})-l|<\varepsilon$
whenever $n\geq N$. Here, $l=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{k}(n)}'(r_{k}).$
Let $N_{1}=\max(k,N)$. Let $n\geq N_{1}$ be arbitrary. Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(n) & = & (\theta_{1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{k})\circ(\theta_{k+1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{n})(n)
\end{eqnarray*}
and $(\theta_{k+1}\circ\ldots\circ\theta_{n})(n)\geq n\geq N$, so
$|f_{\phi(n)}'(r_{k})-l|<\varepsilon$. This shows that $(f_{\phi(n)}'(x))_{n}$
is convergent.

We further prove that $(f_{\phi(n)}'(x))_{n}$ is convergent
for all $x\in(a,b)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Denote $g_{n}=f_{\phi(n)}'$.
Let $x\in(a,b)\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.
Choose $y\in(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x-y|<\frac{\varepsilon}{4M}$.
Note that $(g_{n}(y))_{n}$ is convergent, so we can choose $N$ such
that $|g_{m}(y)-g_{n}(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ whenever $m,n\geq N$.
Let $m,n\geq N$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|g_{n}(x)-g_{m}(x)\right| & = & \left|[g_{n}(y)-g_{m}(y)]+[g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(y)]+[g_{m}(y)-g_{m}(x)]\right|\\
 & \leq & \left|g_{n}(y)-g_{m}(y)\right|+\left|g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(y)\right|+\left|g_{m}(y)-g_{m}(x)\right|\\
 & \leq & \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+2M|x-y|\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $(g_{n}(x))_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence is
convergent.

---

Claim 3: Define $g:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{n_{k}}'(x)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_{\phi(k)}'(x),$
where $\phi$ is as in Claim 2. Then, $g$ is continuous.

Proof of Claim 3: Let $x_{0}\in(a,b)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.
Define $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{M}$. Let $x\in(x_{0}-\delta,x_{0}+\delta)\cap(a,b)$
be arbitrary. Choose $n$ such that $|g(x_{0})-g_{n}(x_{0})|<\varepsilon$
and $|g(x)-g_{n}(x)|<\varepsilon$. We have estimation
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|g(x)-g(x_{0})\right| & \leq & \left|g(x)-g_{n}(x)\right|+\left|g_{n}(x)-g_{n}(x_{0})\right|+\left|g_{n}(x_{0})-g(x_{0})\right|\\
 & < & \varepsilon+M|x-x_{0}|+\varepsilon\\
 & \leq & 3\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $g$ is continuous at an arbitrary point $x_{0}$
and hence $g$ is a continuous function.

---

Now, define $G:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $G(x)=\int_{c}^{x}g(t)dt$.
By fundamental theorem of calculus, $G'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.
On the other hand, since $(g_{n})_{n}$ is uniformly bounded, by Lebesgue
dominated convergence theorem, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
G(x) & = & \int_{c}^{x}g(t)dt\\
 & = & \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{c}^{x}f_{n_{k}}'(t)dt\\
 & = & \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left\{ f_{n_{k}}(x)-f_{n_{k}}(c)\right\} \\
 & = & f(x)-f(c).
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $f(x)=G(x)+f(c)$. It follows that $f$ is differentiable and
$f'=G'=g$ is continuous. That is, $f\in C^{1}$.